# How to normalize data in R excluding certain rows?

Tags: r, scale, rows, bioinformatics, normalizing

I am trying to graph some sequencing data and want to exclude Chromosome 4 data (where the rows in the first column have a '4') when I scale it. Chromosome 4 may skew the normalizing, so I want to exclude it from my scale() function. Is there any way to do that? Right now, I have:

```
preMBT_RT <-preMBT_RT %>% mutate_each_(funs(scale(.) %>% as.vector),vars=c("Timing"))
```

^But is there any way I can indicate IN that function to exclude rows with '4' in the first column?? Or is the only way to do that to create a NEW data frame which does not have chromosome 4 data in it?

Here is a sample of what the data frame looks like in brief:

```
Chromosome     Location     Replication Timing
1              3748         -0.0001
4              1847101      0.000302   <-row I would want to exclude
20             1234         0.000102
...            ...          ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the `filter()` method, like:

```
preMBT_RT <-preMBT_RT %>% filter(Chromosome!=4) %>% 
mutate_each_(funs(scale(.) %>% as.vector),vars=c("Timing"))
```

Comment: you can also do this: `preMBT_RT <-preMBT_RT %>% 
mutate_each_(funs(scale(.) %>% as.vector),vars=c("Timing")) %>% filter(Chromosome!=4)  `

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems like the most elegant solution for my problem.

Comment: I have an additional question - will this code exclude chromosome 4 from the scaling *calculation* but still scale the data? Or does it exclude the chromosome 4 data from even being scaled?